# SSH GPO Windows 2016

Tags: group-policy, windows-server-2016

Does a gpo exist for allowing ssh access on windows server 2016.?
I have tried google and more specifically, https://gpsearch.azurewebsites.net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no built in policies to permit this.

I would guess the closest option to install via policy would be to create a Powershell script and assign that and configure that as a startup script.  Or perhaps use a policy to deploy a scheduled task that runs a Powershell script that installs and configures ssh.